# Action Script 3 / Flex builder 3 : How to make a diagram

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, diagram

I want to make a diagram with either flash CS4 or flex builder 3, don't know with one would be the best for the job.

More about the task:

I want to send in values external to the swf file.
The swf-file takes the vaules and makes a diagram of it using x and y values.

Any advise or tips of where i can make this is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!
jesper

Comment: can you explain things clearer a bit ? do you want to draw a diagram or write an actionscript program in flash/flex that allows for user to dynamically draw diagrams ?

Comment: extending @George's comment, Flash would be ideal for former case; if you're writing a program with which user can dynamically draw (like an image editor, you don't need flash/flex - just plain ActionScript project that can be compiled with the free mxmlc compiler will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

if you're generating all of the visual information yourself then you don't need flash at all. you can generate a swf file from flexbuilder/flashbuilder (or even [flashdevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page) with the free [flex sdk](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK)). flash cs4 itself is pretty much essential if you need to draw assets too (eg animations etc), but if you don't need that then don't bother spending the money. :)